# RegEx for removing non ASCII characters from both ends

Tags: python, regex

I have to loop multiple times using this code, is there a better way?

```
item = '!@#$abc-123-4;5.def)(*&^;\n'
```

or

```
'!@#$abc-123-4;5.def)(*&^;\n_'
```

or

```
'!@#$abc-123-4;5.def)_(*&^;\n_'
```

The one I have like this did not work

```
item = re.sub('^\W|\W$', '', item)
```

Expect

```
abc-123-4;5.def
```

The final goal is to keep only remove anything not `[a-zA-Z0-9]` from both ends while keeping any chars in between. The first and last letter is in class `[a-zA-Z0-9]`

Comment: Not sure what you're looping multiple times for exactly. Do you mean on the same input string? `^\W+|\W+$` ?

Comment: Use `^\W+|\W+$`

Comment: @CAustin @sin thanks, It is the plus sign `+`, I did use a recursive func which I thought it should be wrong, Thanks!

Comment: @CAustin, it is very close, except underscore

Comment: @sin, it is very close except the underscore

Comment: What do you mean in the title by removing non ascii characters? These are ascii characters: !@#$

Comment: Your title shall be "RegEx for removing non word characters from both ends"

Comment: I don't want to be "that-guy" but, why not filtering it directly in python code instead of doing a complex regex ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To trim *non word characters* (upper `\W`) from start/end but also add the underscore which belongs to *word characters* `[A-Za-z0-9_]` you can drop the `_` into a [character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) together with `\W`.

```
^[\W_]+|[\W_]+$
```

[See demo at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/QjPrYH/1). This is very similar to @CAustin's answer and @sln's comment.

---

[To get the inverse <sup>demo</sup>](https://regex101.com/r/QjPrYH/5) and match everything from the first to the last alphanumeric character:

```
[^\W_](?:.*[^\W_])?
```

[Or with alternation <sup>demo</sup>](https://regex101.com/r/QjPrYH/2) (`|[^\W_]` for strings having [just one alnum](https://regex101.com/r/QjPrYH/3) in it).

```
[^\W_].*[^\W_]|[^\W_]
```

Both with `re.DOTALL` for multiline strings. Regex flavors without try [`[\s\S]*` instead of `.*` <sup>demo</sup>](https://regex101.com/r/QjPrYH/6)

Answer (score 13):

[This expression](https://regex101.com/r/ySNdja/1/) is not bounded from the left side, and it might perform faster, if all your desired chars would be similar to the example you have provided in your question:

```
([a-z0-9;.-]+)(.*)
```

Here, we're assuming that you might just want to filter those special chars in the left and right parts of your input strings.

You can include other chars and boundaries to the expression, and you can even modify/change it to a simpler and faster expression, if you wish.

[image]

#### RegEx Descriptive Graph

This graph shows how the expression would work and you can visualize other expressions in this [link](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24):

[image]

If you wish to add other boundaries in the right side, you can simply do that:

```
([a-z0-9;.-]+)(.*)$
```

or even you can list your special chars both in the left and right of the capturing group.

#### JavaScript Test

```js
const regex = /([a-z0-9;.-]+)(.*)$/gm;
const str = `!@#\$abc-123-4;5.def)(*&^;\\n`;
let m;

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
    // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
    if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
        regex.lastIndex++;
    }
    
    // The result can be accessed through the `m`-variable.
    m.forEach((match, groupIndex) => {
        console.log(`Found match, group ${groupIndex}: ${match}`);
    });
}
```

#### Performance Test

This JavaScript snippet shows the performance of that expression using a simple loop.

```js
const repeat = 1000000;
const start = Date.now();

for (var i = repeat; i >= 0; i--) {
 const string = '!@#\$abc-123-4;5.def)(*&^;\\n';
 const regex = /([!@#$)(*&^;]+)([a-z0-9;.-]+)(.*)$/gm;
 var match = string.replace(regex, "$2");
}

const end = Date.now() - start;
console.log("YAAAY! \"" + match + "\" is a match  ");
console.log(end / 1000 + " is the runtime of " + repeat + " times benchmark test.  ");
```

#### Python Test

```
import re

regex = r"([a-z0-9;.-]+)(.*)$"
test_str = "!@#$abc-123-4;5.def)(*&^;\\n"
print(re.findall(regex, test_str))
```

#### Output

```
[('abc-123-4;5.def', ')(*&^;\\n')]
```

Comment: You forgot the right bound, and I don't think you need to capture the first part, since it's to be discarded.

Comment: It is a conceptual error to assume this `([a-z0-9;.-]+)(.*)` is the inverse of this `^\W+|\W+$` The actual inverse is this `(\w(?:.*\w)?)` where $1 becomes the new string. https://regex101.com/r/ySNdja/2

Comment: Your regex is left biased since `([a-z0-9;.-]+)`  matches  ",,,,`abc....l---`"  which clearly is not the inverse of `^\W+|\W+$` https://regex101.com/r/p0IC0v/1

Comment: I'm not trying to make a better expression, just pointing out a flaw, just trying to help...

Comment: great answer, I actually use it in some other regex, but not this question. Thanks!

Comment: emma, why do you delete all of your comments? it makes it difficult to follow the thread

Comment: @Emma it's kind of annoying

Answer (score 9):

You can accomplish this by using the carat `^` character at the beginning of a character set to negate its contents. `[^a-zA-Z0-9]` will match anything that isn't a letter or numeral.

```
^[^a-zA-Z0-9]+|[^a-zA-Z0-9]+$
```

Answer (score 3):

First of all, you can cut off some very special cases by **removing the escape characters**:

```
item = re.sub(r'\\[abnrt]', '', item)
```

After that lets remove the `_` character from `\W`, from what you get `[^a-zA-Z0-9]`.

Your **final regular expression** will be: `(^[^a-zA-Z0-9]+)|([^a-zA-Z0-9]+$)`

```
item = re.sub(r'(^[^a-zA-Z0-9]+)|([^a-zA-Z0-9]+$)', '', item)
```

[See explanation...](https://regex101.com/r/KEFsCR/1)

[image]

[Here you can visualize your regular expression...](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=(%5E%5B%5Ea-zA-Z0-9%5D%2B)%7C(%5B%5Ea-zA-Z0-9%5D%2B%24))